# Is unitarity/normality of operator independent of inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inner-products

There is a problem in my textbook:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ be linear operator with matrix representation in standard basis as 
>   $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3\\
>  4 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
>   Can we find inner product in $\mathbb{C}^2$, such that $A$ will be:
>
> 1. Normal operator?
> 2. Unitary operator?
>
> In case that such inner product exists, find one.

My approach is, since $AA^* \neq A^* A$ and $AA^* \neq I$ such inner product cannot be found. But is it correct?

Edit: The problem is in chapter in my Linear Algebra textbook, which deals with Riesz representation theorem and introduction to adjoint, normal, unitary e.t.c. operators, if it helps.

Comment: Doesn't $A^*$ depend on the inner product?

Comment: @Chappers my bad, it is. How can I find one? From condition of $\langle Ax, y\rangle = \langle x, A^*y\rangle$?

Comment: If $\langle x, y \rangle$ is given by $y^* G x$, you can find $A^*$ by solving the equation $GA=BG$ for $B$: there's a unique solution $A^*=GAG^{-1}$ since $G$ is invertible. For a complex space there need to be some more complex conjugates in there in general

Comment: And then from having my $A^*$ I can find inner product. Thanks!

Comment: And notice you have a shortcut for unitaryness by looking at the determinant.

Comment: Mm. You also need an overall transpose in my formula, in fact. Finding the correct definition is left as an exercise.